# How to write a function in scheme that finds an element in a list with car & cdr?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm new to scheme and i don't know how to do this. I have this list:

```
 (define-struct store(id desc price))
 (define master (list
   (make-store 1 'milk 2.50)
   (make-store 2 'meat 3.29)
   (make-store 3 'eggs 1.99)
   (make-store 4 'cereal 2.99)
   (make-store 5 'bread 2.79)
   (make-store 6 'soda 1.29)
   (make-store 7 'water 4.99)))
```

and i want to create a function that will take an id and return the desc and price. But im not sure where i should start. Can someone help?

Edit: Is there a way to do this with car and cdr? I know that i can retrieve the id desc and price with (store-id),(store-desc),and (store-price) using car and cdr as needed, but how would i incorporate that into a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [struct](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html) accessors and some function for [list searching](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28part._.List_.Searching%29) or [filtering](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28part._.List_.Filtering%29). Struct accessors are named like this: if you have struct `store` and want to get value of slot `id`, that accessor will be named `store-id`:

```
(store-id (make-store 1 'milk 2.50)) => 1
```

Then use [filter](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=filter#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) or [findf](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=find#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._findf%29%29) to get your result and create new list with values from two other slots.

```
(define (find-by-id obj id)
  (let ((found (findf (lambda (e)
                        (= (store-id e) id))
                      obj)))
    (if found (list (store-desc found)
                    (store-price found))
        #false)))

(find-by-id master 2)
(find-by-id master 5)
(find-by-id master 8)
```

**EDIT:** Version with `car` and `cdr`. If list of structures is empty, `#false` is returned. Else function checks first struct in list. If `struct-id` = `id`, it will return list with values. Else, this function is called again, only with `cdr` of list.

```
(define (find-by-id lst id)
  (cond ((null? lst) #false)
        ((= (store-id (car lst)) id)
         (list (store-desc (car lst))
               (store-price (car lst))))
        (else (find-by-id (cdr lst) id))))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with car & cdr?

Comment: @Kazumi411 Yes, I added that way to my post.